# Need help in writing into an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am facing issues in writing into iframe, I am able to identify the iframe but I am not able to write anything into the frame. Whenever I try to write into the frame I am getting below error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 211 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:33'
```

[This](http://puu.sh/kHxAM/f1227ba7b3.png) is the screenshot of my HTML Code.

**HTML Snippet:**

```
<div id="offer_description_field" class="control-group wysihtml5_type description_field ">
    <label class="control-label" for="offer_description">
        Description
    </label>
    <div class="controls well">
        <ul class="wysihtml5-toolbar" style="">
        <textarea id="offer_description" class="bootstrap-wysihtml5ed" rows="3" name="offer[description]" data-richtext="bootstrap-wysihtml5" data-options="{"csspath":"/assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css","jspath":"/assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js","config_options":"null"}" cols="48" style="display: none;"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="_wysihtml5_mode" value="1">
        <iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: separate; border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; clear: none; float: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); outline-offset: 0px; padding: 4px 6px; position: static; z-index: auto; vertical-align: middle; text-align: start; box-sizing: content-box; box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset; border-radius: 4px; width: 327.8px; height: 60px; top: auto; left: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto;"></iframe>
        <p class="help-block">Required. Add offer description.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I create a simple HTML file with above code snippet I am not able to interact with element. Manually I am able to write anything inside this iframe when it is coming with full code base. Looks like it is replacing the textarea with iframe. Not sure how to deal with this type of element.

[This](http://puu.sh/kHzv9/4a499aa9b5.png) is how it appears on the panel.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: Iframes are not suppose to be written into for security reasons

Comment: You are only allowed to write to frames that are on the same domain as the parent page. Otherwise it is considered a security risk.

Comment: is there any workaround by which I can write into this... Manually I am able to write into this field. This is a mandatory field otherwise form wouldn't be submitted.

Comment: Actually, wysihtml still has the `textarea` for you to write into if you need to - wysihtml just represents the HTML contents inside the text area in an iframe that is editable (I think it gets updated on change).

Comment: but when I am using below code to write into textarea `driver.findElement(By.id("offer_description")).sendKeys("Whatever I want to write");`
It says Element not visible to interact with.

Comment: Please move your code snippet into the question so everyone will be more likely to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error doesn't have to do with the `IFRAME`. In fact, the element you are interacting with isn't inside the IFRAME. The reason you can't interact with it is stated in the error.

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

The element is not visible. If you look at the `TEXTAREA` element, it is marked with `style="display: none;"` which is why it is not visible. Selenium was designed to interact with the page as a user would and so will not interact with hidden elements. You will need to approach this problem as a user would... how would a user get that text area to appear? I'm assuming click something, etc. You will need your script to execute whatever a user would do, then the `TEXTAREA` will become visible, and will be able to be interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

you should takecare of following things while working with frames :
1.Select the frame .
then enter into the text/textarea.
**Note:** sometimes the elements are not in the visible area in the UI hence we may required to take the element into view port , following below code spinet before entering  into the text/textarea :
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

2.then deselect the frame .

Hope this would work for you .

Answer (score 0):

Switch into that `iframe` either by `id/class` using following code

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("Enter id of element")));
```

OR

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.class("Enter class of element")));
```

Once you switched to the frame select the element with your normal steps.
like

```
driver.findelement(By.id/class/css/xpath("Enter Element id/class/css/xpath"));
```

Then, if you want to select any other element from the main frame, simply go back to your main frame with following code

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```